# Can you add helium to an already inflated soccer ball to make it lighter?

Tags: weight, volume, displacement

I was in a meeting today and a scenario was presented that began with two soccer balls of identical weight (both inflated).  One of the balls then had helium added to it, and became heavier in the process...

Is it possible (theoretically) to add helium to an already (for the most part) inflated soccer ball and end up with it weighing less?
I realize that adding helium to a balloon (for example) causes it to rise due to the air the helium displaces - but in the soccer ball context the volume of the ball is relatively static (hence it becoming "heavier").
I am curious if there was a (really big) soccer ball that had a bit of inflation left to go, could the ball actually become lighter?  It looks like the the volume displaced would have to be six times the volume added (in my meager attempt to answer this question), but not sure how that would actually work out in the context of a soccer ball (even a really big one).
If so, I'd be interested in the mathematics behind said context - in other words, what volume would said soccer ball be before and after (and resulting calculations)?
Thanks to anyone that has the time and inclination to answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the soccer ball already has its full shape you cannot decrease it's weight by only adding helium.

You would also need to remove air.

Helium balloons float because the helium weighs less than air.  A ball full of air already weighs more than air.  Adding helium can only increase the weight unless you remove air.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - thanks.  As I rejected on the context, I realized that the ball will become "lighter" up to the point the helium displaces air (and in this case that can only occur if ball is not fully inflated).  It doesn't matter the size of the soccer ball - only if it has room to expand (displacing air).  Thanks again!

Comment: reflected (not rejected)